# C# .net 3.5+ Dictionary<string, string> key/value pair displaying value as default choice – MVC select list

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, key, key-value

I’m trying to figure out any way to retrieve certain elements of a particular class instance for use within a drop-down list that I’m attempting to perform some maintenance on. The goal is to select and assign all Contacts to a key/value pair string array (Contacts being a related entity of Company, specifically, a 1:n relationship - 1 company has multiple contacts) then selecting the first contact’s first and last name attributes out of the sequence where the Boolean class attribute, Primary, is set to True.

```
public class Company 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

The following code:

```
private Company CreateViewModel(Company company)
{
    var contacts = _contactService.CompanyContacts(company);

}

public Dictionary<string, string> CompanyContacts(Company company)
            {
                    var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                    foreach (var contact in company.Contacts)
                    {
                            var key = string.Format("{0} {1}|{2}", contact.FirstName, contact.LastName, contact.IsPrimary());

                            var val = string.Format("{0} {1}|{2}", contact.FirstName, contact.LastName, contact.IsPrimary());

                            if (results.ContainsKey(key)) continue;

                            results.Add(key, val);
                    }

                    return results;
            }

    public void InitContactList(Dictionary<string, string> contacts)
    {

        var firstOrDefault = contacts
            .Where(x => x.Key.Contains("true"))
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        var selectedContact = contacts.FirstOrDefault().Value;

            if (firstOrDefault != null)
            {
                var selectedContact =  firstOrDefault;

                ContactList = new SelectList(contacts, "Key", "Value")
                .SelectByText(selectedContact.ToString()).ToList();
            }

            ContactList = new SelectList(contacts, "Key", "Value")
                .SelectByText(selectedContact.ToString()).ToList();
    }
```

doesn't display the first 'is primary' contact by default in the select-list though. I would like the first isPrimary=1 contact to be the first selection in the picklist. I’m pretty sure the firstOrDefault variable in the InitContactList needs to have the key do something other than .contains(“true”) Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that sticks out to me with what you have in the code is the

```
x.Key.Contains("true")
```

part.  This does a string comparison with case sensitivity.  Your value for the dictionary item converts the boolean to a string with either the value "False" or "True".  The simplest solution would be to change your linq where statement to:

```
x.Key.Contains("True")
```

but this may not be the best solution, as this looks for "True" in any part of the string, and is still case sensitive. A "better" solution would be to use a comparison method that allows for case insensitivity. An extension method I have used a few times in projects is this:

```
public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toCheck) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        return false;
     return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}
```

and you could change the where statement to:

```
x.Key.Contains("True", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

If you are not using .NET 3.0 or greater, you can easily just change that to a static utility method.

Comment: thank you for your response your code snippet worked for me I appreciate the help.